# not able to run wordcount example in mapreduce 2.x

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to execute mapreduce word count exaple in mapreduce 2.x in java.... I had create the jar but while executing it is showing the error like WordMapper class not found in my package but I had declared that in my package.....please help me to solve the issue......

**this is my WordCount driver code :**

```
package com.mapreduce2.x;

public class WordCount {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException
{
    Configuration conf=new Configuration();

    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job job= new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job(conf, "Word_Count");


    job.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(WordReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

}}
```

**And this is my WordMapper Class :**-

```
public class WordMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text,IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one=new IntWritable(1);
private Text word=new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    String line=value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(line);

    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);

    }


}}
```

**WordReducer code -**

```
public class WordReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{


public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    int sum =0;

    while(values.hasNext())
    {
        sum= sum+values.next().get();
    }

    context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}}
```

**it is showing the folowing error while executing-**

```
15/05/29 10:12:26 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/05/29 10:12:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1432876892622_0005_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mapreduce2.x.WordMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2076)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mapreduce2.x.WordMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2074)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the class name while running the JAR file or you can specify the main class name while creating the JAR file.

If you are running without class name then specify the class name while running the JAR.

Use the command 
**hadoop jar word.jar com.mapreduce2.x.WordMapper /input /output**

Here word.jar is the JAR file name.

OR

you can also include the main class name while creating a jar file.
Steps:
File --> export --> JAR --> location --> then click next --> it asks for selecting main class --> select the class and click OK

After that you can run the jar file with the command

**hadoop jar word.jar /input /output**

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: wordcount is my main class and I am specifying that while executing....

hadoop jar wordcount.jar com.mapreduce2.x.WordCount /input/output

but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the commented line below
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
//job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:(IN Linux/Unix)

1. Remove the package name in the java code.
2. Inside the directory which contains the java program, create a new directory called classes.  ex: `Hadoop-Wordcount -> classes , WordCount.java`
3. compile: `javac -classpath $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-annotations-2.7.1.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d ./classes WordCount.java`
4. create a jar `jar -cvf wordcount.jar -C ./classes/ .`

5.run `bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/Hadoop-WordCount/wordcount.jar WordCount input output`